# mysqlimport: Error: 1083, Field separator argument is not what is expected

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I'm trying to import a csv file into a Wordpress database table.

Here's what I entered in the SSH command line (with my personal details removed):

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=, --fields-enclosed-by=" 
--fields-escaped-by=" --lines-terminated-by=\n\r --verbose --local - 
uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASENAME wp_posts.csv
```

And here's the output I got:

```
mysqlimport: Error: 1083, Field separator argument is not what is expected; 
check the manual, when using table: wp_posts
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can edit my original command to get the CSV file imported?